# usb device powered direct by AC

Tags: usb, ac, converter

I have a USB ventilator, that I want to use while i'm soldering to bring some fresh air to my atelier. I don't want to have my computer there to do it. So I was thinking to connect it to a 5v regulator and connect it direct to AC. I google around but didn't find any diagram or project that I could use as base. Basically I want to have something like:

```
AC -> Switch On/off -> 5v Regulator USB Port -> GRD.
```

any idea, links, etc?

**UPDATE**:

Links to buy iphone charger isn't what i'm looking for.  I would accept it if at least, the iphone charger have an on/off switch

Comment: Use an [iPhone charger](http://www.amazon.com/Apple-iPhone-iPod-Charger-Cable/dp/B004WPJB9U/ref=sr_1_23?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1339279848&sr=1-23&keywords=iphone+charger), if you have one.

Comment: Do you have a bench power supply? Then use this and salvaged USB port. If not: buy/build one, you will need it.

Comment: @ox6d64 i have it but the ventilator is usb. I could destroy the usb and connect directly the pins to energy, but that i didn't want to do

Comment: USB simply provides 5V, the current is usually only limited by a simple fuse. So directly connecting 5V DC to the right USB pins will not hurt the fan.

Answer (score 2):

for EU: http://www.dealextreme.com/p/usb-power-adapter-charger-for-iphone-4-white-100-240v-eu-plug-48615

for us: http://www.dealextreme.com/p/usb-power-adapter-charger-for-ipod-series-iphone-3g-4-red-100-240v-us-plug-65369

for about 2.5 bucks ***free shipped*** you have a 110-240 Vac to 5Vdc 1Amp
while a regular USB port 0.5 amps delivers.

Answer (score 1):

Chargers don't tend to have an on/off switch. Use a mains extension cable which has a switched outlet on the end, if your outlet isn't switched.

You cannot connect a regulator to a.c. without reducing the amplitude from 110v rms/220v rms down to 7-30v and without rectifying it to d.c. first. There are lots of other questions on this site with the basic schematic of a linear power supply in the answer if you want to build it yourself. It is also possible to construct a switched mode power supply which is what the Apple and many other phone chargers use to be small and light but this is very complicated.